# Script for printing all PDF's in folder and moving them after printing

Tags: pdf, batch, printing, cmd.exe

I'm looking for some solution for my problem. I have directory with multiple PDF files. I want my script to print it all and move them to directory "Completed" after printing. I have very basic knowledge about cmd, so I tried to complete it using batch, but without success.

```
for %%i in (*.pdf) do ^
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t
move %%i \Completed
```

Comment: You need `%%i` after `/t` (otherwise acrord32 doesn't know what file to print ...)

Comment: [Adobe Reader Command Line Reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/619158)